# How to manage Large amount of Data in GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I Have a table with 10000 records, so I want call only 15 Records at a single time using Stored procedure.

At the Next time call only next 15 Reocords and go On...

Please Help me out!!...If Possible Give Code With Example and Stored Procedure...Thank You!!!

Comment: Did you do a search before asking? In the WHERE clause of the SQL you just do a Between or > / <. This is something you get taught in the first lesson of SQL. So instead of *oh I dont know, I'll ask Stackoverflow*, think - *what are some options for managing a large amount of Data in GridView?  I know, I could use Search, Date Range, Pagination or etc.* Let me google that **C# ASP.Net gridview search pagination**. It's best you work out how to do this simple stuff yourself. Last tip, ditch the "Pls give me teh codez with example,  stored procedure, in a project, that conforms to my job...".

Answer (score 0):

> Use paging in gridview as AllowPaging="true" then use
>   OnPageIndexChanging Event and give us PageSize see below example

```
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" AllowPaging="true"
                OnPageIndexChanging="OnPageIndexChanging" PageSize="10">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="Column_Name" HeaderText="Header Name" />
                    <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="Column_Name" HeaderText="Header Name" />
                    <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="Column_Name" HeaderText="Header Name" />
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
```

> Now bind the gridview with database on Page_Load Event

```
     protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                if (!IsPostBack)
                {
                    BindGrid();
                }
            }

        private void BindGrid()
        {
            string conStr = @"Your connection string here";
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Table_Name"))
                {
                    using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
                    {
                        cmd.Connection = con;
                        sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                        using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                        {
                            sda.Fill(dt);
                            GridView1.DataSource = dt;
                            GridView1.DataBind();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

> for pages use newPageIndex on OnPageIndexChanging event

```
    protected void OnPageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        BindGrid();
    }
```